# Could internet cookies turn into malicious A.I. that could launch nuclear missiles?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, computers, internet, nuclear-weapons

Nowadays many websites used internet cookies which is in fact a piece of code or a script that can store user data and other preferences, it usually cannot be executed by itself think of it like your personal secretary who manages all your daily routine, meetings, agenda, reports etc. Since everything are connected to the internet, could internet cookies turns into A.I. smart enough to silently track and gain access to a nuclear silo or tactical sub and fires a nuclear warhead at random?

Comment: You want to program an AI on javascript? Good luck with that.

Comment: No. Cookies themselves cannot turn into an AI. By whom? Who executes these cookies?

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr - Technically, you can can download "initiating" cookie file that is called, say, every few seconds, but doesn't jumpstart the AI until all of AIs files (other cookies) are on users computer. Making user to download all of them is a whole other problem however.

Comment: @MrScapegrace Then they're still plain text. You also need an interpreter / executor to run the cookiecontent. And who'd download a evilAIinterpreter.zip?

Comment: See season hijacking

Comment: **"which is in fact a piece of code or a script"** this is false. By design they are not, and browsers and OSes got good enough at preventing them from being maliciously (ab)use them in such way. Other attack vendors are more cost effective.

Comment: Session (not season) hijacking has *nothing whatsoever* to do with cookies being "a piece of code or a script", which as has already been pointed out they are not. Cookies are data, nothing else. Any browser or other HTTP UA that attempts to actually execute cookies as code has a *huge* bug sitting right there in the open.

Comment: @MrScapegrace Javascript is Turing complete, which is all you need. Mind you, I'm not saying Javascript would be anyone's *preferred* language for creating an AI, but if an AI can be implemented in any Turing-complete language, then an AI can be implemented in *any* Turing-complete language. For a deeper discussion on this, I recommend the [cs.se] stack.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr No one would (hopefully) be stupid enough to get fooled by "evilAIinterpreter.zip", however, is it not a quite likely scenario if it was called "cute_kittens_do_funny_stuff.mp4.exe"? ;)

Comment: @Mrkvička Those people don't deserve any better than being ruled by an evil AI :D

Comment: @AlexanderVonWernherr if the AI is providing justice, can it really be called evil? Some theology suggests the Devil is the most obedient servant of God.  ;-)

Comment: @SRM Think about Lawful Evil in D&D :-)

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr same as it was for jpg with IE in 2009 http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/14282/info

Comment: @MolbOrg yes, but it required precisely prepared jpg file. And it was what, 8 years ago? And cookies, as plain text without any assumed lengths of anything, are much harder to cause overflow. Anyway, this is only loosely related issue, as the whole idea that cookies are scripts is false.

Comment: Not a great question but that doesn't make it off topic.

Comment: @Mołot "And it was what, 8 years ago?" - do not even begin with that, I'm not a security expert, but how about executing arbitrary commands the "php -c" which was not noticed for 10 years or so. But point was, it do not have to be executed(kinda), and that is just an example of that. OP's answer is yes, but highly improbable, never happens improbable, but in first place, because it implies sporadic spontaneous birth of AI with goals. But as far as some 0day vulnerability will exist (and that is just matter of time) it can make such attack possible. Yahoo situation -> it can be created.

Comment: @MrScapegrace Ask on PPCG.SE, then!

Answer (score 15):

I think you misunderstand cookies, or how powerful they are.
Cookies are not executed. They hold text-data, and that text-data is read.

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie):
A cookie consists of the following components:

```
Name
Value
Zero or more attributes (name/value pairs). Attributes store information such as the cookie’s expiration, domain, and flags (such as Secure and HttpOnly).
```

So, no code that can turn into an AI, at least not with current technology and cookies.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in comments, cookies are not executable code. Therefore, they are not executed. Discussion on Information Security.SE [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126261/can-cookies-carry-viruses). The big takeaway is that a bug that allowed execution of cookies as code would be a very big deal in computer security terms. It is almost certain that such a bug does not exists in any of the [major browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#/media/File:Browser_usage_share,_2009%E2%80%932016,_StatCounter.svg).

Another relevant factor is that cookies are [not that big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key). It would be hard to get enough code into a single browser using cookies to run an 'AI', before hitting the browser's [cookie limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381526/what-are-the-current-cookie-limits-in-modern-browsers).

There are ways around all these things, but at that point you are talking about a plain ol' computer virus, or worm, or SkyNet or something. So the answer is, there is no real way to make a distributed AI work the way you are describing.